# how to insert the textbox values to the database mysql using php oops concept when clicked on the Submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="database.php" method="post">
Name : <input type ="text" name = "Name"/>

Number  :<input type ="text" name = "Number"/>
<input type ="submit" value = "submit" name="submit"/>

</form>
</body>

</html>
<?php

class Database
{

    var $host;
    var $user;

    var $pass;
    var $data;

    var $con;
    var $table;

    var $db;
     public function controls()

    {
       $this->host="localhost";

        $this->user="root";
        $this->pass="";

        $this->data="employeedatabase";
       }

    public function connection()
    {

        $this->con = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
    }

    public function tablename()
    {

        $this->table=mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee(name,number) VALUES ('".$_POST[name]."','".$_POST[number]."')");

    }
public function databaseconnection()

    {
        $this->db=mysql_select_db($this->data,$this->con);

    }
}

$name=new Database();
$name->controls();

$name->connection();
if(!($name->con))

{
    echo 'Error: ' . mysql_error();

}
$name->databaseconnection();

$name->tablename();
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME, FIRST TIME IM ADDING THE QUERY IM NEW TO PHP OOPS CONCEPT..how to insert the textbox values to the database mysql using php oops concept when clicked on the Submit button

Comment: Please define "PHP Oops concept", I've never heard of it.

Comment: using functions(object oriented programming) in php

Comment: So you're trying to write a database class in PHP using OOP, wich allows you to insert a textbox value in a MySQL database. Correct?

If correct - please edit your question:
1 - What is the question? Is it not working? Do errors show up? What do you want us to tell you?
2 - What is your code? What have you tried?
3 - What are you using? PHP? MySQL? MySQLi? What versions?

Don't just slam your code here, and shout allcaps "PLEASE HELP ME, FIRST TIME IM ADDING THE QUERY IM NEW TO PHP OOPS CONCEPT". Kindly ask a question, and we'll answer you. This is a Q&A site, not a code dump place.

Comment: yes correct,inserting textbox values to table(MYSQL) on click of submit button USING PHP,OOPS.if i run the form it just downloads the same file.using NOTEPAD++ and also with dreamweaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the html form

```
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Name : <input type ="text" name = "Name"/>

Number  :<input type ="text" name = "Number"/>
<input type ="submit" value = "submit" name="submit"/>

</form>
</body>
```

This php file containing the class is named db.php

```
<?php
class db
{
    public $host;
    public $user;
    public $pass;
    public $data;
    public $con;
    public $table;
    function db()
    {
        $this->host="localhost";
        $this->user="usern";
        $this->pass="passwrd";
        $this->data="dbname";   
    }   
    public function connect()
    {
        $this->con=mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
        if(!$this->con)
        {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
        $sel=mysql_select_db($this->data, $this->con);
        if(!$sel)
        {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
    public function insert($name,$number)
    {
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename(name, number) VALUES('$name', '$number')");
        if(!$sql)
        {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This script is for the php file which you specify in the "action" attribute of your html form i have named it "process.php"

```
<?php
    include'db.php';
    $name=$_POST['Name'];
    $num=$_POST['Number'];
    $n=new db();
    $n->connect();
    $n->insert($name,$num);
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much..im very new to the php oops concept,thanku for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question(i don't see any question here) i would like to point out
some facts,

1. Please don't use class and it's object in the same page,the very idea of OOPS is to bring reusability to the code so what is the point of using both the class and it's object in the same script ? save the class in a seperate php file and then include the class in your php script using

   ```
   include'filename.php'
   ```

   then you can use the class in any script with similar requirments
2. Don't set the class variables in a function , provide values to the variables in a constructor ,so that you wouldn't have to call a seperate function for setting values to class variables ,as contructor function is invoked everytime an object is created
3. specify the access control modes for the class variables,either "public" or "private"or "protected" 
    here's the modified class file , named  class.db.php

   ```
       class Database
        {

   var $host;
   var $user;

   var $pass;
   var $data;

   var $con;
   var $table;

   var $db;
    function Database()

     {
      $this->host="localhost";

       $this->user="root";
       $this->pass="";

       $this->data="employeedatabase";
      }

   public function connection()
   {

       $this->con = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);
   if(!$this->con)
       {
       echo mysql_error();
       }
   }

   public function tablename()
   {

       $this->table=mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee(name,number) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['number']."')");
   if(!$this->table)
       {
       echo mysql_error();
       }
   else
       {
         echo "success";
       }

   }
   public function databaseconnection()
   {
           $this->db=mysql_select_db($this->data,$this->con);
       if(!$this->db)
          {

           echo mysql_error();
          }

       }
   }
   ```

And here's the script for the database.php

```
<?php
include'class.db.php';
$name=new Database();
$name->connection();
$name->databaseconnection();
$name->tablename();
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..but database is not getting connected..getting error as Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\database1.php on line 3.. and i edited the class name and function which was was same, i changed it and executed,nw no error but when i click on button the file itself is getting downloaded..please tel me how to add submit button and weather to add onclick keyword in submit type followed by function name.please see on the previous code :)

Comment: how to insert the textbox values to the database mysql using php oops concept when clicked on the Submit button, if you have any of your code on this please put here :)

Comment: @user2924931 Are you running this from localhost ?
what do you mean "the file is getting  downloaded " ?
if the file is getting downloaded how did you got the error ?