# How to search the textbox values in the database mysql using php oops concept when clicked on the Search button

Tags: php, mysql

In this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620553/7137902), it's explain very good how to add values to the database. Now I need exactly the same but now as a search function. I added one textbox ("Name") and one button ("Search") to the html form - now pointing to search.php instead of process.php. Both use the db.php. Now I tried to implement search(name) in db.php. Could you please help me?

search.php:

```
<?php
include'db.php';
$a=$_POST['username'];
$n=new db();
if (empty($a))
{
    echo "Error!";
} else {
    $n->connect();
    $n->search($a);
    echo "Done!";
}
?>
```

function in db.php (here I need prepared statements for select * from ### where):

```
public function search($a)
{
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$a'");
    if(!$sql)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    } else {
        echo $sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to 'ping' or message users using the @user syntax in questions. Instead, request clarification in comments (you'll need to earn a  bit more rep first).

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Without more reps, I cannot contact him directly but I need his help...

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to earn 50 rep though, and if you can't do that, just ask the question generally (see [ask]) and someone else will probably help.

Comment: Thank you for the information! However, can anybody help me?